# Firestore sort by value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a filter for my application
It will filter by the datas' category, but I also want to sort them by its rating, higher rating will be on the top.
I wrote the following code, but the orderby() function having issue.

```
        const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('Locations').where(
            "category", "==", type).orderBy("rating").get();
        
        if (snapshot.empty){
            console.log('No matching documents');
            return;
        }
        
        snapshot.forEach(doc=> {
            locList.push(doc.data());
        })
```

and here is my firestore data look like
[image: firestore data]

Comment: What response are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

To sort values from largest rating to smallest rating, specify the ordering as descending. Change the `orderBy` function to:

`.orderBy('rating', 'desc')`

Comment: im getting the error of `[Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: The query requires an index. You can create it here:...`

Comment: You need to create the index on the firebase console. Follow the link displayed (after the ...) and you should be good.

Comment: I'm creating the indexes manually, but should the two data be "Ascending" or "Descending" or "Array"? Also should the query scopes be "Collection" or "Collection group"?

Comment: Collection ID : Locations .
Fields : -
category - Ascending
rating - Descending.
Query Scope : "Collection".

Comment: @AdamNeuwirth Hi Adam, what if i need to do smallest to largest? change desc to asce?

Comment: @Lee by default it is ascending

Comment: @AdamNeuwirth what do you mean by default?  so change to .orderby('rating')?